# Does a new branch named as an old re-named branch inherit its commits?

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

A few days ago I renamed a branch (following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999938/1391441)) named `emcee` in [my repo](https://github.com/asteca/ASteCA) to `emcee_old`. Then, I created a new branch with the same name (`emcee`) but branching from a *different* point in my `develop` branch. Here's how Github shows this process:

[image]

The issue is that now if I check a file in the *new* `emcee` branch, it contains a commit that was made to that file in the *old* `emcee`. For example the [.gitignore](https://github.com/asteca/ASteCA/blob/emcee/.gitignore) file in the new branch shows a commit that was made in 2017 in the old branch:

[image]

Even weirder is that if I access the history of that file (in the new branch) *that commit is not there*:

[image]

Why is going on here?

Comment: I've found GitHub's "network graph" to be error-filled and nearly useless, myself.

Comment: So far I've had a good experience with Github's network graph and branch management. This issue threw me off completely.

Comment: Probably a matter of expectations, then. :-) I always have to clone the repository and examine the actual graph. The network graph appears to be intended for something to do with forks and other projects, and it may have some meaning there, but I have yet to decipher it.

Comment: Also, I am by no means a `git` power-user like you (not even close), so our experiences with such a tool will clearly be different. For my level of `git` proficiency, the network graph is quite a useful feature.

Comment: @Gabriel I had the same issue documented here: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/955

Comment: @GabrielFair fortunately I didn't use GitHub's merge tool and did it all by hand. I have also contacted support, since my repo is public perhaps they can check what's going on and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Git does not carry commits between similarly-named branches.

So you created a branch, then renamed it and created a new one by the same name?  I have done this in git v1.8.4.2 successfully, though without using Github.

I suspect an problem with Github's interface.  You can test this by cutting it out of the loop and studying your repo's history locally, on the command line.  Try running `git log --graph --all` command in a terminal window and study the output.  This will display all of your branches, and their converging/diverging history.  Also try `git log --graph --all .gitignore` to limit the history report to the file in question.  I expect you will see a more predictable result, different from what Github displays.

This becomes more complex if there are other users of your repository.  A collaborator could accidentally restore the old branch during a push.  However [your link](https://github.com/asteca/ASteCA) indicates that you don't have to worry about this, as this is a solo effort.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that this is some weird behaviour of Github and not just my imagination Kevin.

Comment: You're welcome.  The 'git log' command has a lot of fancy options that make it a lot easier to visualize history.  For example, [refer to this page.](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log)